# RSpec: Expecting a message multiple times but with differing parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I currently have some expectations set up on a mock with consecutive calls:

The spec:

```
@my_mock = mock("a_mock")
@options1 = {:some => "option"}
@options2 = {:some_other => "option"}
@first_param = mock("first_param")

@my_mock.should_receive(:a_message).with(@first_param, @options1)
@my_mock.should_receive(:a_message).with(@first_param, @options2)
```

However, i get the following:

```
Mock "a_mock" received :a_message with unexpected arguments
  expected: (#<Spec::Mocks::Mock:0x81b8ca3c @name="first_param"{:some => "option"})
   got: (#<Spec::Mocks::Mock:0x81b8ca3c @name="first_param">, {:some_other => "option"})
```

When I debug this, the first expectation IS getting called. Do I have to specify anything else before I can expect consecutive calls with the same message but differing parameters?

Comment: When I try your example, it works fine for me.  What version of Ruby and RSpec are you running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try creating your mock as a null object to ignore extra method calls.  Each of your expectations will still have to be met, but they won't step on each other.

```
@my_mock = mock("a_mock").as_null_object
```

This follows the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern, in which any extraneous messages are just ignored.  It is useful with mocks when you want to make sure a method gets called with certain parameters, but you don't care if it is called with other parameters or if any other methods get called.

Comment: This does help. However I'm not sure what this is doing. Can you explain?

Comment: I updated my answer with a little extra info about null objects.  I'm not a pattern or testing expert, but I hope it helps a bit.